# Getting Azure Active directory token

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure Account, now I'm trying to get token in an console application to manage resources (i.e. create a resource group etc):

```
string userName = "xyz@gmail.com";
string password = "XXXXXXXXX";
string directoryName = "xyzgmail.onmicrosoft.com";
string clientId = "guid-of-registered-application-xxx";
var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(userName, password);
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + directoryName);
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientId, credentials);
```

On **AcquireTokenAsync** call I have

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException:
>   'accessing_ws_metadata_exchange_failed: Accessing WS metadata exchange
>   failed'

Can anybody help, please?

**Update: how I tried to create a resource group under newly created user**

```
var jwtToken = result.AccessToken;
string subscriptionId = "XX-XX-XX-YY-YY-YY";
var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(jwtToken);
var client = new ResourceManagementClient(tokenCredentials);
client.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;
var rgResponse =  await client.ResourceGroups.CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync("myresgroup77777",
                new ResourceGroup("East US"));
```

Here I got another exception

> 'The client 'newaduser@xyzgmail.onmicrosoft.com' with object id
>   'aaa-aaa-aaa-aaa' does not have authorization to perform action
>   'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourcegroups/write' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/XX-XX-XX-YY-YY-YY/resourcegroups/myresgroup77777'.'

Comment: Do you have a link to the resource where you saw it used this way? [I don't even see an overload that matches what you are doing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Did you assign a role to the user? The permissions to execute `Windows Azure Service Management API` is granted to the application that assumes the identity of the logged in user. However that user needs to be in a role that has permission to create a resource group in a subscription. Try by assigning in-built `Contributor` role at the subscription level to this user.

Comment: @GauravMantri awesome! it works! Just a minor questions, can I log in via initial user (which is owner) not cremating a new one?

Comment: You should be able to do so. I tried to look up the 1st error you were getting but couldn’t find anything conclusive regarding that. Let me post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting the first error, but the second error is because the signed in user does not have permission to perform the operation (as mentioned in the error message).

When you assign the permission to execute `Windows Azure Service Management API`, it is actually assigned to the application which assumes the identity of the signed in user.

In order to perform `Create Resource Group` operation in Azure Subscription, that user must be in a role that allows this operation to be performed. You can try by assigning built-in `Contributor` role at the Azure Subscription level to this user.

Also, regarding using `login.windows.net` v/s `login.microsoftonline.com`, it is recommended that you use latter. When you use `login.windows.net`, it gets automatically redirected to `login.microsoftonline.com`. Using `login.microsoftonline.com` will save you one redirection.